# How to create a .GTF file?

Tags: bioinformatics, genome

I am new to bioinformatics and programming. I would greatly appreciate some help with step-by-step instructions on how to create a `.GTF` file. I have two cancer cell lines with different green fluorescent protein (GFP) variants knocked-in to the genome of each cell line. The idea is that the expression of GFP can be used to distinguish cancer cells from non-cancer cells. I would like to count GFP reads in all cancer cells in a single cell RNA-seq experiment. The single cell experiment was performed on the 10X Chromium platform, on organoids composed of a mix of these cancer cells and non-cancer cells. Next generation sequencing was then performed and the reference genome is the human genome sequence, GRCh38. To 'map' and count GFP reads I was told to create a .GTF file which holds the location information, and this file will be used retrospectively to add GFP to the human genome sequence. I have the FASTA sequences for both GFP variants, which I can upload if requested. Where do I start with creation of a .GTF file? Do I create this file in Excel, or with, for example BASH script in a Terminal? I have a link to a Wellcome Trust genome website (https://www.ensembl.org/info/website/upload/gff.html?redirect=no) but it is not clear what practical/programming steps are needed. From my reading it seems a GFF (GFF3?) file is needed as an intermediate step. Step-by-step instructions would be very welcome to create the `.GTF` file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think what you want to do is described in the "Add a marker gene to the FASTA and GTF" section at the link below. You basically just want to add your marker genes to the existing human (or mouse) reference, which comes packaged in the 10X workflow. 

https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/using/tutorial_mr

Comment: That's great, thanks for this! I will try it out once our deeper sequencing is complete.

Answer (score -1):

one can just download it from GenCode. For example, the lastest release for human is here: https://www.gencodegenes.org/human/

Comment: How does this answer the question of creating a `.GTF` file?